# Stata -- predict after regression by group_id

Tags: regression, stata, predict

I have to run regressions by group_id and then generate the predictions.  It doesn't seem like predict allows the "by" option.  Is there a way I can predict after running regressions by group_id?  The data are stacked by group_id.

The regression command I am thinking of using is as follows:

`by group_id: reg y x`

Will appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon further thinking (and reading an old article by Nick Cox), it occurred to me that `statsby` can be used to avoid the loop and speed up the program. Here's a comparison of their speed.

Let's first prepare example data.

```
set more off
timer clear

webuse nlswork,clear
keep idcode ln_wage age
drop if missing(idcode, ln_wage, age) // drop all missing
drop if (idcode[_n]!=idcode[_n+1] & idcode[_n]!=idcode[_n-1]) // drop groups with one case
```

This is the `statsby` approach. `statsby` automatically creates a new dataset that overwrites the existing one. Therefore, I proceed with the following steps:

1. save the original data first (as tempfile "master"),
2. run `statsby`,
3. save intercepts and slopes (as tempfile "using"),
4. load the original data,
5. merge the two data,
6. calculate predicted values.

This is the code.

```
timer on 1
tempfile master using
save `master'
qui statsby _b[_cons] _b[age],by(idcode) :regress ln_wage age
save `using', replace
use `master'
qui merge m:1 idcode using `using'
gen yhat1=_stat_1+_stat_2*age
timer off 1
```

Compare this to the `levelsof`/`foreach` approach.

```
timer on 2
levelsof idcode, local(levels)
qui gen yhat2=.
foreach l of local levels {
    qui reg ln_wage age if idcode==`l'
    qui replace yhat2=_b[_cons]+_b[age]*age if idcode==`l'
}
timer off 2
```

The first approach takes only half of the time the second approach does.

```
.     timer list
1:     22.11 /        1 =      22.1150
2:     56.44 /        1 =      56.4350
```

Comment: Aspen Chen, when running this code, it only gives me one yhat per idcode.  However, the yhat should be generated for all the observations under that idcode.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: Great catch. I apparently failed to include the independent variable in the prediction. The revised code is posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it in a loop

```
levelsof group_id, local(levels) 
foreach l of local levels {
  reg y x if group_id == `l'
  predict pred_`l'
}
```

Comment: I thought of looping it but then I have 10,000 group_ids and I thought it would be really slow to run the loop.  Isn't that the case?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run 10,000 regressions, then that will take the time it takes. Note that wanting `predict` to support `by:` is out of the question as when you run `predict` only the last of 10,000 sets of regression results is visible to it. (`by:` here is a prefix command, not an option.)

Comment: What I was envisioning is that if we could output the betas (as stacked next to the dependent and explanatory variables) by group_id, then we could generate the yhat as stacked next to the dependent variable (also by group_id).  Am wondering if that is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1542743 It is possible. Add `gen yhat=.` before the loop, and replace the `predict` line with `replace yhat=_b[_cons]+_b[x] if group_id == \`i'` The same logic would go for beta. In Stata 13, see item 13.5 in the help manual for more explanation on how to assess coefficients and standard errors.

Comment: I suppose I still cannot get rid of the loop?

Comment: I can't think of any solutions without looping in Stata. Perhaps there's a way in Mata. If you know to use R, its vectorized operations are theoretically faster, but I haven't really compared them.

Comment: @user1542743 just to add, with respect to measuring the time, you may run a first couple with the [timer](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?timer) function to get estimate time for the 10k regressions.